# How to use angular material table in angular dart

Tags: angular, typescript, dart, html-table, angular-material

I am working on `angular dart` project and I need to implement angular material table in my application.

I am following this guide https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples. But the example given in the document is for `typeScript`. I want to implement that same table in my `angular dart`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

package:angular_components does not provide data table yet

But you can use skawa package that contains a data-table
https://pub.dev/packages/skawa_material_components